# HTTParty parsing sub-component of response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, httparty

the following controller action

```
@result = HTTParty.post(
  'https://test.co.uk/interface/search', 
  :body => [...]
```

has a response.  The response is not being viewed in expected json parsed structure.  It is a long hash...

```
{"versionNumber"=>"5.5", "availabilitySummary"=>{"totalAvailable"=>102, "totalOnRequest"=>0}, 
"structures"=>[... big array]
```

The array has a number of sub-hashes `"currencyCode"=>"USD", "info", "options"=>[sub-array]`.
I would like to access the array of stractures first in the view form (for testing purposes, before eventually commiting results to database.)

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if possible, move the HTTParty stuff to a worker. This way, you will avoid your app crashing if the server you are hiting for the data is unavailable. Otherwise, make sure to wrap the HTTParty stuff in a `begin - rescue - end` block and catch appropriate exceptions there.
Second of all, passing the entire JSON to a view and accessing it in the view is a bad practice because it drastically slows down template rendering. Instead, create a service object that would return the data model that's easy to access in a view. Give it a name that somehow describes what it relates to - MyJsonParser is probably not the best name, but you know what I mean. Implement a `#call` method which returns the data for you in a format that's easy to access in the view.

`my_json_parser.rb`

```
class MyJsonPArser
  def call
    response = post_request
    parse_structures(response)
  end

  private

  def post_request
    HTTParty.post(...)
  end

  def parse_structures(response)
    structures = response["structures"]
    # do more work with the big structures array ...
  end

end
```

`your_controller.rb`

```
def your_method
  @data = MyJsonParser.new.call
end
```

`your_view.html.erb`

```
<% @data.each do |item| %>
  <div><%= item %></div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: While helpful, as my question points out, there are three 'items' and I wish to work with on the third item -  `structures`  how can this be invoked specifically?

Comment: almost there... what I intend is how can I ask for the key say `structures` and work with that key's array...  because I am going to have to do that with sub-arrays as well.  And who knows if the index value will stay constant from the server, whereas the key will.

Comment: I forgot about grabing the structures array from the response. See my answer, I have updated it. You access the key from the hash just like in any other hash by referencing it either by string or a symbol: hash["structures"]. In this case you want to access it by a string since it is not HashWithIndifferentAccess but a simple JSON object.

Comment: functions.  This is pertinent as many sub-arrays are going to be served up and they are best recognised by the key. [I ralise this is a sepaerate question... but it is a pertinent consequence] Are there any perfomance hits from this approach that can be alleviated?

Comment: There shouldn't. Accessing the structures array from response is not a problem here, however the performance depends on how you then work with the array. Don't forget to write tests for it ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do like this:

```
@result["structures"][0]


@result["structures"][1]
```